# Using SmartEnum Along With NSwag

Tags: c#, nswag

I am trying to use https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum as an alternative to enums. But I could not figure out how NSwag would generate enums for these classes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting library! What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You've almost certainly solved this yourself already, but for those (like me) coming here from Google:

You'll need to write your own custom `ITypeMapper` to get the correct schema output. Here's a generic mapper that'll make the enum appear as a string in the schema, with all the enum values set:

```
public class SmartEnumTypeMapper<TEnum, TVal> : PrimitiveTypeMapper
    where TEnum : SmartEnum<TEnum, TVal>
    where TVal : IComparable<TVal>, IEquatable<TVal>
{
    public SmartEnumTypeMapper() : base(typeof(TEnum), x => {
        x.Type = JsonObjectType.String;

        foreach (var item in SmartEnum<TEnum, TVal>.List)
        {
            x.Enumeration.Add(item.Name);
        }
    }) { }
}

public class SmartEnumTypeMapper<T> : SmartEnumTypeMapper<T, int>
    where T : SmartEnum<T>
{
}
```

Then add the TypeMapper when configuring NSwag:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerDocument(opts => {
    opts.TypeMappers.Add(new SmartEnumTypeMapper<YourEnumHere>());
});
```

This results in schema output like the following:

```json
"fruit": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": ["apple", "pear", "banana", "peach"]
}
```